# People.People.searchDirectoryPeople() query with multiple email addresses

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-people-api

In a Google Apps Script I need to query the Google user profile picture URL of many coworkers.

Here is a working example for a single user:

```
searchDirectoryPeople('jimmy.neutron@example.com');

function searchDirectoryPeople(query) {
  const options = {
    query: query,
    readMask: 'photos,emailAddresses',
    sources: ['DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE']
  }
  const people = People.People.searchDirectoryPeople(options);
  if(people && people.people) {
    Logger.log('size: '+people.people.length);
    people.people.forEach(person => {
      let url = '';
      let email = '';
      if(person) {
        if(person.photos && person.photos[0]) {
          url = person.photos[0].url;
        }
        if(person.emailAddresses && person.emailAddresses.length) {
          person.emailAddresses.forEach(item => {
            if(item.metadata && item.metadata.sourcePrimary) {
              email = item.value;
            }
          });
        }
      }
      Logger.log('email: '+email+': '+url);
      //Logger.log('person: %s', JSON.stringify(person, null, 2));
    });
  } else {
    Logger.log('no people.people');
  }
}
```

I found out that I can query all `jimmy` people:

```
searchDirectoryPeople('jimmy');
```

I have the email address of all employees. I could loop through a big list of 1000+ employees one by one, but this is not practical. I am looking for a way to query multiple email addresses. The docs at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchDirectoryPeople are cryptic for the query. I tried many things like these but nothing works:

- `'jimmy.neutron@example.com, carl.wheezer@example.com, cindy.vortex@example.com'`
- `'jimmy.neutron@example.com OR carl.wheezer@example.com OR cindy.vortex@example.com'`

I am looking for a query by list of email addresses as input, such as:

```
[ 'jimmy.neutron@example.com', 'carl.wheezer@example.com', 'cindy.vortex@example.com' ]
```

Is it possible to have an `OR` query in `People.People.searchDirectoryPeople()`?

---

**UPDATE 2022-05-31**

I tried looping through all emails and ran either into a quota limit or a script runtime limit.

@Lorena Gomez's answer is correct: First use the `People.People.listDirectoryPeople()` to get the resource names of all email address, followed by `People.People.getBatchGet()` to get the profile picture URL by resource names. The former limits to 1000 employees per call, the latter limits to 200. This works in our case where we have 1k+ email addresses as input, and 20k+ employees returned by `listDirectoryPeople()`.

Working code:

```
const emails = [
  'jimmy.neutron@example.com',
  'carl.wheezer@example.com',
  'cindy.vortex@example.com'
];
let emailToUrl = getGoogleProfilePictureUrls(emails);
Logger.log('emailToUrl: %s', JSON.stringify(emailToUrl, null, 2));
// expected output:
// emailToUrl: {
//  "jimmy.neutron@example.com": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/xxxx=s100",
//  "carl.wheezer@example.com": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/xxxx=s100",
//  "cindy.vortex@example.com": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/xxxx=s100"
// }

function getGoogleProfilePictureUrls(emails) {
  let options = {
    readMask: 'emailAddresses',
    sources: ['DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE'],
    pageSize: 1000
  }
  let run = 1;
  let resourceNameToEmails = {};
  let result = {};
  while(run === 1 || result.nextPageToken) {
    if(result.nextPageToken) {
      options.pageToken = result.nextPageToken;
    }
    result = People.People.listDirectoryPeople(options);
    Logger.log('request #' + (run++) + ', got '+result.people.length+' resource names');
    result.people.forEach(person => {
      if(person.emailAddresses) {
        person.emailAddresses.forEach(obj => {
          if(obj.metadata && obj.metadata.sourcePrimary) {
            let email = obj.value
            if(emails.indexOf(email) >= 0) {
              resourceNameToEmails[person.resourceName] = email;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
    Utilities.sleep(200);
  }
  run = 1;
  let emailToUrl = {};
  let resourceNames = Object.keys(resourceNameToEmails);
  let resourceNameBatch = resourceNames.splice(0, 200);
  while(resourceNameBatch.length) {
    options = {
      personFields: 'photos',
      resourceNames: resourceNameBatch,
      sources: [ 'READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE' ]
    };
    result = People.People.getBatchGet(options);
    if(result && result.responses) {
      Logger.log('request #' + (run++) + ', got '+result.responses.length+' urls');
      result.responses.forEach(person => {
        let primaryUrl = '';
        let url = '';
        if(person.person && person.person.photos) {
          person.person.photos.forEach(photo => {
            if(photo.metadata && photo.metadata.source && photo.metadata) {
              url = photo.url;
              if(photo.metadata.source.type === 'PROFILE' && photo.metadata.primary) {
                primaryUrl = url;
              }
            }
          });
        }
        let email = resourceNameToEmails[person.person.resourceName];
        emailToUrl[email] = primaryUrl || url;
      });
    }
    Utilities.sleep(200);
    resourceNameBatch = resourceNames.splice(0, 200);
  }
  return emailToUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like with `Method: people.searchDirectoryPeople` you can only specify one person at a time.

Another option could be [People.People.getBatchGet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people#get_the_person_for_the_user) which will require an extra step but provides you information about a list of the people you specify. The request would look something like this:

```
const options = {
    personFields: 'photos,emailAddresses',
    resourceNames: [
      'people/account_id',
      'people/account_id',
      'people/account_id'
    ],
    sources: [
      'READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE'
    ]
  }
  
  const people = People.People.getBatchGet(options);
```

You can get the user's `account_id` with [Method: people.listDirectoryPeople](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople)

Comment: Thank you @Lorena, this is the correct answer. For anyone interested, see **UPDATE 2022-05-31** in my question for working code.

Answer (score 0):

#### How about this?

```
function searchDirectoryPeople(query) {
  const options = {
    query: query,
    readMask: 'photos,emailAddresses',
    sources: ['DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE']
  }
  const people = People.People.searchDirectoryPeople(options);
  if(people && people.people) {
    Logger.log('size: '+people.people.length);
    people.people.forEach(person => {
      let url = '';
      let email = '';
      if(person) {
        if(person.photos && person.photos[0]) {
          url = person.photos[0].url;
        }
        if(person.emailAddresses && person.emailAddresses.length) {
          person.emailAddresses.forEach(item => {
            if(item.metadata && item.metadata.sourcePrimary) {
              email = item.value;
            }
          });
        }
      }
      return {"imgurl":url,"email":email}
    });
  } 
}

function searchPlus(emailArray) {
  let oA = [];
  emailArray.forEach(e => {
    oA.push(searchDirectoryPeople(e))
  });
  if(oA && oA.length) {
    return oA;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cooper. That would call the API 1000 times if I have 1000 email addresses, which could hit the quota. My question was if it is possible to call `People.People.searchDirectoryPeople()` with a list of email addresses, which still would require multiple calls using paging, but I could return up to 500 per request.