# How to resolve the missing information problem while using the People API in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-people-api

I'm trying to use the People API with Google Apps Script. The objective is to retrieve the info of a directory and then write it in a Google Spreadsheet sheet. The directory contains the information of 330 people. The first problem is that when I use the code (see below), it only retrieves the info of 85 people; every time I've runned it the result has been the same.

The second problem problem is that I can't get the names, nicknames or anyother information about the people in the directory. I can only get emails, phone numbers and ID's, so I would like to know if I'm missing something or I have to trya another method from the GAS People API.

Here's the code. Note that even if I write "names" or "nicknames" in the readmask, it doesn't return that info:

```
function obtenerDirectorio2() {

  var directorio =  People.People.listDirectoryPeople({
    readMask: 'names,emailAddresses',
    sources: 'DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE',
    mergeSources: 'DIRECTORY_MERGE_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT'
  });


  let objeto = JSON.stringify(directorio, null, 2); 

  let objeto2 = JSON.parse(objeto);

  for(let i = 0; i < objeto2.people.length;i++){
    Logger.log(correo = objeto2.people[i]);
  }

}
```

Comment: You might need to use the `pageSize` property and iterate using the `nextPageToken` until your script get all the people listed in the directory. Here is a related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/72398370/1595451. If you need further help, focus your question on a single problem.

Comment: Are using the readMasks from [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople)?

Comment: Try changing the sources and mergeSources

Comment: Yes, I'm using those readMasks.

Answer (score 0):

This API method doesn't work correctly at the moment.
There is an issue on Google's tracker for this bug.

Here's a link:
[people.listDirectoryPeople (or searchDirectoryPeople) response doesn't include names](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196235775)

In the last comment they promise fixing it in Q3 of 2023.

#### Solution:

The solution, as a temporal workaround until Google fixes `People API`, is to use different API to fetch directory users with names, which is part of the [`Admin SDK API`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/overview), the [`Directory API`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides).

Don't let `Admin` in the name confuse you, it doesn't require you to be an admin in the org to use its methods to retrieve non-restricted data.

This is the method you need to use: [`users.list`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list).
To use it, you will need to add this OAuth scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly`.

Be sure to:

- set `viewType` parameter to `domain_public`, otherwise you'll need admin access to fetch restricted data
- set `customer` parameter to `my_customer` alias to represent your account's customerId

Comment: Hey, thanks. I used the Admin SDK API and it worked.